# Not able to read tiff file after saving it from base64 string in java

Tags: java, image, base64, jpeg, tiff

I'm not able to open tiff image file from local machine after saving it from base64 string(from eclipse)

Below is the code for the same.

```
Byte[] decod = Base64.decodeBase64(base64encodedstring);
FileOutputStream str = new FileOutputStream(tifffilepathtosave);
BufferedOutputStream bstr = new BufferedOutputStream(str);
bstr.write(decod);
bstr.close();
```

When I tried to open the file

Alert saying *this is not a valid bitmap file.or its format is not currently supported*

But im able to open original tiff files.

Is there any other way to save tiff images properly, or am I missing anything in above code.

PF below link to access base64 string which I'm decoding and saving as a tiff file.
https://github.com/rajinikanthd08/ProjectA/blob/main/Tiffbase64%20(1).txt

This is the link of code which I'm getting response from web service and getting base64 encoded string  and trying to saving in tiff.
https://github.com/rajinikanthd08/ProjectA/blob/main/SignatureDisplay.txt

Comment: I was able to download and decode your TIFF file now. After a manual inspection of the file, I agree with Paint and ImageIO in that the file is corrupted or malformed. Required TIFF tags are missing, have wrong order and contains values too large for the file. I would try uploading a valid TIFF file to your service to validate if it's your service that corrupts it, or if this file was just broken to begin with...

Comment: Yes, I'm checking with concerned team who will push the data to us through service so will see, btw thank you for sharing knowledge, meanwhile is there anything I can do.